# Рабочий запрос не работает в MySQL 5.7 this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: php, mysql

При выполнении запроса из под php, появляется следующая ошибка:
 `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'rusintech.pt.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
Array`

Сам запрос следующий:

```
UPDATE product_tara_test AS p 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id FROM product_tara_test pt 
      WHERE price IS NOT NULL AND price > 0 AND id_stockroom = ? 
      GROUP BY id_product) as B
ON p.id = B.id
      SET
      p.tara = '',
      p.meter = '',
      p.id_city = NULL,
      p.type_unit = '',
      p.weight_b = '',
      p.weight_n = '',
      p.comment = '',
      p.reserve = '',
      p.year_kpp = '',
      p.provide = '',
      p.sutured = '',
      p.characteristics = '',
      p.date_export = '',
      p.price_nds = NULL,
      p.active = 1
```

Почему то запрос не работает из под php, если я через редактор MySQL выполняю запрос, запрос проходит без ошибок. На локальном компьютере запрос так же работает успешно. Но на сервере появляется ошибка и именно если он выполняется через php 
На сервере версии:
**PHP 7.1.4**
 **MySQL 5.7.18-ndb-7.6.2**
На локальной машине:
**PHP 7.0.7**
 **5.7.13-log**

Comment: группируешь ты по id_product, а выборку ведешь по id .... вот он и ругается..... типа он не уверен, что в итоге выберутся именно те строки, которые ты думаешь. что выберутся. может id не уникальны и тогда выберется первая попавшаяся запись....... по идее это можно отрубить в настройках (кажется в настройках что-то типа sql_mode=only_full_group_by) или в запросе дописать `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))` чтоб проигнорить но...... лучше переписать более правильно запрос

Comment: где-то видел хорошую статью на русском об этом, не могу найти

Comment: Подскажите, как именно переписать в запрос?

Comment: Ответ уже подсказали)) еще может поможет статья [Группировка в MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html) ....... там как раз описание проблемы и методы решения  есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы исправления проблемы:

1. Выяснить, одному значению product_tara_test.id_product соответствует строго одно значение product_tara_test.id или несколько (не по факту, а на уровне структуры таблицы и подсистемы целостности данных). Если одному - из SELECT-a убрать GROUP BY и добавить DISTINCT. Если НЕ одному - обернуть id в групповую функцию (например, MIN(id)). Наилучшее решение.
2. Установить на уровне сессии (вообще или только для этого запроса) значение ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY в состояние OFF. Решение очень среднего качества.

Установить в OFF:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@SESSION.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
```

Установить в ON:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = CASE FIND_IN_SET('ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',@@SESSION.sql_mode)
                       WHEN 0 THEN CONCAT('ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,',@@SESSION.sql_mode)
                       ELSE @@SESSION.sql_mode
                       END;
```

3. Добавить в выражение группировки поле product_tara_test.id. Худшее решение, может повлиять на логику (и соответственно на результат) запроса.